# Create new array from iterating JSON objects and getting only 1 of its inner array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6

See jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/remenyLx/2/

I have data that contains objects that each have an array of images. I want only the first image of each object.

```
var data1 = [
    {
    id: 1,
    images: [
      { name: '1a' },
      { name: '1b' }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    images: [
      { name: '2a' },
      { name: '2b' }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    images: []
  }
];

var filtered = [];
var b = data1.forEach((element, index, array) => {
    if(element.images && element.images.length) 
      filtered.push(element.images[0].name);
});

console.log(filtered);
```

The output needs to be flat:

```
['1a', '2a']
```

How can I make this prettier?

I'm not too familiar with JS `map`, `reduce` and `filter` and I think those would make my code more sensible; the `forEach` feels unnecessary.

Comment: [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) , [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: your realization is good

Comment: you don't need `b` variable, it will always be `undefined`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you can [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out elements without proper `images` property and then  [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) it to new array:

```
const filtered = data1
  .filter(e => e.images && e.images.length)
  .map(e => e.images[0].name)
```

To do this in one loop you can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function:

```
const filtered = data1.reduce((r, e) => {
  if (e.images && e.images.length) {
    r.push(e.images[0].name)
  }
  return r
}, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce()` to return this result.

```js
var data1 = [{
  id: 1,
  images: [{
    name: '1a'
  }, {
    name: '1b'
  }]
}, {
  id: 2,
  images: [{
    name: '2a'
  }, {
    name: '2b'
  }]
}, {
  id: 3
}, {
  id: 4,
  images: []
}];

var result = data1.reduce(function(r, e) {
  if (e.hasOwnProperty('images') && e.images.length) r.push(e.images[0].name);
  return r;
}, [])

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

All   answers are creating NEW arrays before projecting the final result :    (`filter` and `map` creates  a new array each) so basically it's creating **twice**.

Another approach is *only to yield expected values* :

Using iterator functions

```
function* foo(g)
{

    for (let i = 0; i < g.length; i++)
    {
        if (g[i]['images'] && g[i]["images"].length)
            yield g[i]['images'][0]["name"];
    }
}

var iterator = foo(data1) ;
var result = iterator.next();

 while (!result.done)
{
    console.log(result.value)
    result = iterator.next();
}
```

This will **not** create any additional array and only return the expected values !

However if you must return an array , rather than to do something with the actual values , then use other solutions suggested here.

https://jsfiddle.net/remenyLx/7/

Comment: Doesn't the OP want an array though? Also, this prints `undefined` when the iterator is finished.

Comment: @CodingIntrigue yeah  fixed tnx. btw I don't think OP knows it doesn't have to be in an array and of course a push can always be called.